# Basic styling for html5boilerplate

Tags: html, css

html5boilerplate is excellent, and I plan to use it. It basically reset browser styling, and provides some tools for optimizing page performance. Is there a styling/themes for html elements to jump start the development. similar to the themes listed at http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#Home★html5-boilerplate-themes , but framework agnostic. In short, I am looking for styling for html elements (as a base for customization) to include in style.css file, right after the comment line that begins with 'Primary Styles'.

Thanks,
Bsr

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for a stylesheet that magically gives a good style to a page without having to do anything? I doubt that exists, since the CSS is built on top of the HTML, and that would require knowing your HTML. There are probably examples of different layouts around the interwebs, but I don't think you are going to find anything similar to a "theme".

Comment: well, theme is possible in this case as html5boilerplate provides the html template with css selectors.. Looking deeper I saw it already provides basic styling, but too basic. I wish for few examples so I don't have to spend too much time on padding, placements etc and aesthetically pleasing. Just looking for a time saver.

Comment: I think what you are looking for are more like guidelines to good style, like:

'"line-height" should be 150% of the font-size'

and stuff like that. I don't think you can get a theme with this sort of stuff, just interesting articles that will help you learn how to build better sites. I'm afraid the main layout has to come from your own mind.